# Weekday as String to number

Tags: python

I am trying to convert my weekday as a string to an int in python here is what I have

```
from datetime import date, datetime, time, time delta
from pytz import timezone

now = datetime.now(timezone('UTC'))
dt_tz = now.astimezone(timezone('US/Eastern'))
dt = dt_tz.replace(tzinfo=None)
weekday = 'Friday'
weekday_as_int = dt.strptime(weekday, "%A")
```

But i get this error

```
ValueError: time data 'Friday' does not match format '%A'
```

Why won't it change `Friday` to a int?

Comment: How are you getting the value of `weekday`?

Comment: @cricket_007 from a POST Request but that shoudnt matter its value is still friday

Comment: Please post working code -- weekday's not defined.

Comment: I think the problem is that Friday is a string, not a date object.

Comment: @hd1 please see working code

Comment: @cricket_007 hmm... maybe how could I turn it into one? with `strftime` maybe?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The right format for a full weekday is `%A`:

```
import time
weekday_as_int = time.strptime('friday', "%A").tm_wday

>>> weekday_as_int.tm_wday
4
```

Count starts with zero for Monday:

```
>>> time.strptime('Monday', "%A").tm_wday
0
```

Some timings:

@Rustem's version:

```
%%timeit
days = dict(zip(calendar.day_name, range(7))); 
days['Friday']
10000 loops, best of 3: 104 µs per loop
```

This version:

```
%timeit time.strptime('Friday', "%A").tm_wday
10000 loops, best of 3: 19.7 µs per loop
```

Looks like `strptime` is five times faster.

Comment: what is `df`? do you mean `dt`

Comment: It means "days since Sunday"

Comment: Check my answer about timing below, I'm disagree.

Answer (score 2):

Fastest way is:

```
import calendar
days = dict(zip(calendar.day_name, range(7))); 
days['Friday']
```

Btw, strptime is slow and is overkill for this trivial operation.

Comparing to @Mike version

```
In [7]: timeit time.strptime('Friday', "%A").tm_wday
The slowest run took 337.46 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.14 µs per loop

In [8]: timeit days['Friday']
The slowest run took 22.05 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached
10000000 loops, best of 3: 54.1 ns per loop
```

Comment: @Mike, I'd say you version cannot be faster. parsing is always slower than picking by key in dictionary. Two things you doing wrong in your measure. 1.  days variable supposed to be calculated once. 2. As far as strptime is slow, python tries cache the results - to help you provide better results - btw, it's not good. If you check my update, you will see that my version is faster

Comment: How about measuring `dict(zip(calendar.day_name, range(7)))` too?

Comment: @Mike, same as multipling your results to 337.46. As I said it was cached. My way is standard - build mapping first, get results after - reuse if needed.

Comment: Agree. Your solution is better for reuse. I was looking for  one-time thing. My solution is better if the date string contains more text, though. Often the questions are out of context and people want to do more than shown.

Comment: > "My solution is better if the date string contains more text, though" - yes, I'm agree.

Comment: Agree on you agreeing. ;)