# python convert day to date integer

Tags: python, python-2.7

I see option converting date `Jan 22 2016` to day `Monday` as a integer `0` using `weekday()`.
But can I convert day as input to integer.
e.g. `Friday` to `4` .
Input is not a date, it's just a day e.g. `Friday`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert datetime to integer in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28154066/how-to-convert-datetime-to-integer-in-python)

Comment: What have you tried? Look into the `datetime` module?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Weekday as String to number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34216472/weekday-as-string-to-number)

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, you need

```
>>> import calendar
>>> list(calendar.day_name)
['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
```

Having this list you can easily find index or build dict from it

Answer (score 3):

There is a friendly `calendar` module

```
import calendar
dict(zip(calendar.day_name,range(7)))['Monday'] #0
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `range(1,8)` ?

Comment: @Learningisamess Yup. Corrected. Thanks